# Problem with theming my application with CSS

Tags: application-development, quickly, css

I'm trying to beautify my program made with Quickly using CSS. I found documentation  http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkCssProvider.html and very useful blog post http://erikos.sweettimez.de/2011/11/24/gtk-3-theme-style-your-applications-2/

According to the above I should be able to use ID selectors, for example:

```
#nameofmywidget {
    font: Ubuntu 12;
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work. Only working way for me is using:

```
GtkEntry {
    font: Ubuntu 12;
}
```

or:

```
.entry {
    font: Ubuntu 12;
}
```

but it's to generic.

Apart from that I'm not able to change `GtkEntry` and `GtkButton` backgrounds. Any help much appreciated.

---------------------EDIT--------------------

I found a way to change `GtkEntry` and `GtkButton` background colours. Instead of using:

```
GtkEntry, GtkButton {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

I've used:

```
GtkEntry, GtkButton {
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code in the widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your .css file using that tutorial code
Then on your widget do :
    self.sample_widget.get_style_context().add_class("sample_class")

Put this in the .css file :

GtkButton.sample_widget 
{
    color : #00FF00
}

Comment: Many thanks! It works! Although it should be  GtkButton.sample_class { color : #00FF00 }

Comment: Glad that I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more specfic with

```
GtkButton.name_of_button {
       background: red;
       }
```

,that way only button widget "name_of_button" will be effected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not work for me.

Comment: Wrong. That coding means "all GtkButton with class name_of_button".

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
GtkButton#nameofmywidget {
    font: Ubuntu 12;
}
```

work?
Howevere. please post your widget code too.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried that before but this also didn't not work. I'll try to post some code later on.